# Iterating an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have framed an array like below

```
iArray = [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, true]
```

**Condtional check:**
If anyone of the value in this array is **`false`** I will be showing an *error* message 
else if everything is true I will be showing *success* message.

I tired below code to iterate, however couldn't frame the logic in it.

```
var boolIteration = iArray.split(',');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < boolIteration.length; ++i) {
    //conditional check
}
```

I'm struggling to iterate the array using the above condition.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with an efficient solution.

Comment: `iArray` is already an array, why are you trying to split it like a string?

Comment: @Kolink inorder to iterate the values in it.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Erm, yeah! `.split` is to convert a *string* into an array by a separator!

Comment: `if(~$.inArray(false, iArray)){...}`

Comment: @A.Wolff Though I wanted to do this JS.  Since you have mentioned that `indexOf` has compatibility issue in IE, I will go with your jQuery solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iArray` is already an array, so there is no need to split it again (split is a method for String, Arrays don't have it)

What you need to do is check the index of a `false` value, if it is there then there is a false value in the array.

using jQuery - the array indexOf is not used because of IE compatibility

```
iArray = [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, true] 
if($.inArray(false, iArray ) != -1){
    //error
}
```

Comment: +1 I thought it would be `indexOf`, but jQuery has a pretty simple method to handle this.  Thank you for your pointers.

Answer (score 4):

No need for jQuery

```
if (iArray.indexOf(false) !== -1) {
    // error
}
```

Also, as previous commenters have already pointed out, `iArray` is already an array, there's no need to use `split` on it.

The `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not available in Internet Explorer below 9. However, this functionality could be easily added with a matching algorithm. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf for compatibility and how to create a workaround.

Comment: the only problem here is the lack of indexOf method for prototype array on older IE versions

Comment: @A.Wolff You are absolutely right. Below IE9 indexOf is by default a no-no, but could be shimmed.

Comment: … and a shim is still better than loading jQuery for something as simple as this. jQuery solutions are only preferable if jQuery is already being used anyway.

Comment: +1 Thank you for showing me the approach in JS.  Since I already using jQuery I will go with the above one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var iArray = [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, 
true, false,true, false, false, false, false, true];

    for (var i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
        if (iArray[i]) {
            alert("success");
        }
        else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i is less than an array? That's a new one.

Comment: Yes. If size of array is 10, then index of his last  element will be 9. First element always has 0 as index.

Comment: @Kolink You're just full of constructive criticism, aren't you?

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev He's trying to be funny and/or clever.  What he should have said is that you should have put `for (var i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++)`

Comment: sorry )) it was my mistake ))

Comment: I'm gonna side with Kolink here. Simply pasting your own script into the console to see that it's not working should be somewhat of a minimum before posting an answer.

Comment: I also agree with Kolink.  Just not his attitude.

Comment: That may be a matter of taste. I too often prefer hinting a problem rather than spelling it out, because the latter doesn't force the person to actually think about it again. He said it a little sarcastically, so what? I'm sure he didn't mean offend anyone.

Comment: @IngoBürk It doesn't work like that here.  People will post almost anything just to get their answer in first, and then edit it to something (hopefully) correct later.  It's called being point-hungry and this site is full of it.  sadpanda.jpg

Comment: Not quite sure what that has to do with anything, but I know the "point-hungriness" problem. I generally don't mind, though, as long as the first version of the answer actually answers the question and the edits simply improve it, add additional perspectives or information. Again, not really the topic here, though.

Comment: @Archer i'm sorry dude but i am answering one in mounth. it doesn't seem such as point-hungriness :( It was just a mistake. My purpose was to show to topi starter that his iArray was already an array.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev No, I'm sorry.  I wasn't referring to you when I made that comment :)

Comment: +1 This was I tried to frame first.  However I found a nice solution in `jQuery`.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Aternatives:

```
if (/false/i.test(iArray)) { }
```

or

```
if ( ''.replace.call(iArray,/true|,/g,'').length ) { }
```

Comment: `.sort` modifies the original array, it does NOT return the sorted array.

Comment: Besides, `sort` has a worse performance than `indexOf`. Even iterating over the array would still be better, if you don't want to use `indexOf`.

Comment: The new alternatives seem unnecessarily cryptic and complicated. Sure one can understand what they do, but not without having a look at it. What's the point of such solutions? When are they ever better than the "normal" solution(s)?

Comment: You are entering the geek zone, beware :3

Comment: If you just want "weird" solutions, here's another one: `iArray.reduce(function (a,b) { return a && b; });`.

Comment: Oh and by the way, there's no need for `join` in the first case. Just `/false/i.test(iArray)` will suffice, because it will call `toString` anyway and we don't care about commas.

Comment: Yup, or `iArray.filter(function(a){return !a});`

Comment: +1 I didn't thought I can do it in `regex`.  However I found an efficient approach in jQuery.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function is nice for checking to see if a particular value is contained within an array.

```
iArray = [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true];
if ($.inArray(iArray, false) >= 0) {
  // the value "false" is contained within the array, show an error message
}
```